# Display GWT RPC result in a new window

Tags: gwt

`GWT Window#open` method can be used to open a new browser window, but it works towards a normal synchronous URL connection. How to display the asynchronous result from the `GWT RPC` call in a new browser window below?

```
        myServiceAsync.getHtmlResult(new AsyncCallback<String>() {
             @Override
             public void onSuccess(String htmlResult) {

//how to display #htmlResult in a new browser window?

             }
             @Override
             public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {}
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You will can use Javascript via [JSNI](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI) to solve this problem.

Method like this does the trick:

```
public native void showWindowWithHtml(String html)/*-{
  var newWindow = $wnd.open("about:blank"); //receive a reference to the window object
  newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html; //works for IE9 and Chrome 
  newWindow.onload = function(){newWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html} //works for Firefox 11

}-*/;
```

When you call, it a new window with specified HTML. Also not that js inside this native method is just an example, I don't guarantee that it will always work everywhere.

You'll have to use this approach since GWT doesn't have built-in support for working with external windows.

Comment: Thanks for your JSNI approach, i'll have a try.